# Regex Search/Replace

Tags: c#, rubberduck

Rubberduck's latest (and greatest?) feature is a regex search/replace:

[image: Regex search/replace]

This is the defining interface:

```
public interface IRegexSearchReplace
{
    List<RegexSearchResult> Find(string pattern, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope = RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentFile);
    void Replace(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope = RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentFile);
    void ReplaceAll(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope = RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentFile);
}
```

And here is the implementation:

```
private readonly RegexSearchReplaceModel _model;

public RegexSearchReplace(RegexSearchReplaceModel model)
{
    _model = model;
}

public List<RegexSearchResult> Find(string searchPattern, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
{
    var results = new List<RegexSearchResult>();

    switch (scope)
    {
        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.Selection:
            results.AddRange(GetResultsFromModule(_model.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule, searchPattern));
            results = results.Where(r => _model.Selection.Selection.Contains(r.Selection)).ToList();
            break;

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentBlock:

            var declarationTypes = new []
            {
                DeclarationType.Event,
                DeclarationType.Function,
                DeclarationType.Procedure,
                DeclarationType.PropertyGet,
                DeclarationType.PropertyLet,
                DeclarationType.PropertySet
            };

            results.AddRange(GetResultsFromModule(_model.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule, searchPattern));
            dynamic block = _model.ParseResult.Declarations.FindSelection(_model.Selection, declarationTypes).Context.Parent;
            var selection = new Selection(block.Start.Line, block.Start.Column, block.Stop.Line,
                block.Stop.Column);
            results = results.Where(r => selection.Contains(r.Selection)).ToList();
            break;

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentFile:
            results.AddRange(GetResultsFromModule(_model.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule, searchPattern));
            break;

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.AllOpenedFiles:
            foreach (var codePane in _model.VBE.CodePanes.Cast<CodePane>().Where(codePane => ReferenceEquals(_model.VBE, codePane.VBE)))
            {
                results.AddRange(GetResultsFromModule(codePane.CodeModule, searchPattern));
            }
            break;

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentProject:
            foreach (var component in _model.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>())
            {
                var module = component.CodeModule;

                if (!ReferenceEquals(_model.VBE.ActiveVBProject, module.VBE.ActiveVBProject)) { continue; }
                results.AddRange(GetResultsFromModule(module, searchPattern));
            }
            break;

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.AllOpenProjects:
            foreach (VBProject project in _model.VBE.VBProjects)
            {
                foreach (var component in project.VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>())
                {
                    var module = component.CodeModule;

                    if (!ReferenceEquals(_model.VBE, module.VBE))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    results.AddRange(GetResultsFromModule(module, searchPattern));
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    return results;
}

public void Replace(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
{
    var results = Find(searchPattern, scope);

    if (results.Count <= 0) { return; }

    var originalLine = results[0].Module.Lines[results[0].Selection.StartLine, 1];
    var newLine = originalLine.Replace(results[0].Match.Value, replaceValue);
    results[0].Module.ReplaceLine(results[0].Selection.StartLine, newLine);
}

public void ReplaceAll(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
{
    var results = Find(searchPattern, scope);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        var originalLine = result.Module.Lines[result.Selection.StartLine, 1];
        var newLine = originalLine.Replace(result.Match.Value, replaceValue);
        result.Module.ReplaceLine(result.Selection.StartLine, newLine);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<RegexSearchResult> GetResultsFromModule(CodeModule module, string searchPattern)
{
    var results = new List<RegexSearchResult>();

    for (var i = 1; i <= module.CountOfLines; i++)
    {
        var matches =
            Regex.Matches(module.Lines[i, 1], searchPattern)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(m => new RegexSearchResult(m, module, i)).ToList();

        if (matches.Any())
        {
            results.AddRange(matches);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

As always, any and all comments are welcome.

Comment: In the `Replace ()` method, how should `results.Count` ever be < 0 ?

Comment: @Heslacher Oh, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`GetResultsFromModule()`**

> ```
> private IEnumerable<RegexSearchResult> GetResultsFromModule(CodeModule module, string searchPattern)
> {
>     var results = new List<RegexSearchResult>();
>
>     for (var i = 1; i <= module.CountOfLines; i++)
>     {
>         var matches =
>             Regex.Matches(module.Lines[i, 1], searchPattern)
>                 .OfType<Match>()
>                 .Select(m => new RegexSearchResult(m, module, i)).ToList();
>
>         if (matches.Any())
>         {
>             results.AddRange(matches);
>         }
>     }
>     return results;
> }
> ```

There is no need to call `ToList()` on the result of the `Regex.Matches().OffType().Select()`. You don't need the check with `.Any()` either, because the returned enumerable won't be `null`.

Calling [`List<T>.AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) will only throw if the enumerable will be null, which won't be the case here.

See also [what-does-linq-return-when-the-results-are-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191919/what-does-linq-return-when-the-results-are-empty)

The other thing I noticed, although it now won't matter anymore is that you are calling `ToList()` but you are checking with `Any()`. Here a check with `matches.Count > 0` would be better.

Starting the `for` loop with `1` seems a little bit strange which any C# developer will notice. I assume this is coming from the VBA stuff, hence this would benefit from a comment.

---

**`ReplaceAll()`**

> ```
> public void ReplaceAll(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
> {
>     var results = Find(searchPattern, scope);
>
>     foreach (var result in results)
>     {
>         var originalLine = result.Module.Lines[result.Selection.StartLine, 1];
>         var newLine = originalLine.Replace(result.Match.Value, replaceValue);
>         result.Module.ReplaceLine(result.Selection.StartLine, newLine);
>     }
> }
> ```

For my taste I see a too excessive usage of the `var` keyword. Without having a IDE with Intellisense at hand one would have to guess what `Find()` will return because it isn't obvious from the right hand side of the assignment. This wouldn't be that worse if the type would be seen in the `foreach` loop. The next one would have problems would be `var originalLine` the whole loop would be more obvious if that `var` would be replaced with `string`.

Wouln't it be easier to read like so

```
public void ReplaceAll(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
{
    List<RegexSearchResult> results = Find(searchPattern, scope);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        string originalLine = result.Module.Lines[result.Selection.StartLine, 1];
        var newLine = originalLine.Replace(result.Match.Value, replaceValue);
        result.Module.ReplaceLine(result.Selection.StartLine, newLine);
    }
}
```

or like so

```
public void ReplaceAll(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
{
    var results = Find(searchPattern, scope);

    foreach (RegexSearchResult result in results)
    {
        string originalLine = result.Module.Lines[result.Selection.StartLine, 1];
        var newLine = originalLine.Replace(result.Match.Value, replaceValue);
        result.Module.ReplaceLine(result.Selection.StartLine, newLine);
    }
}
```

---

**`Replace()`**

> ```
> public void Replace(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
> {
>     var results = Find(searchPattern, scope);
>
>     if (results.Count <= 0) { return; }
>
>     var originalLine = results[0].Module.Lines[results[0].Selection.StartLine, 1];
>     var newLine = originalLine.Replace(results[0].Match.Value, replaceValue);
>     results[0].Module.ReplaceLine(results[0].Selection.StartLine, newLine);
> }
> ```

As already stated in my comment, the returned `List<RegexSearchResult>` can't have a `Count` property with a value `< 0` so the check should be

```
if (results.Count == 0) { return; }
```

and again you have lots of `var` usage here. You should either declare the type of `results` or declare a new variable `result` with the desired type like so

```
public void Replace(string searchPattern, string replaceValue, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
{
    var results = Find(searchPattern, scope);

    if (results.Count == 0) { return; }

    RegexSearchResult result = results[0];

    var originalLine = result.Module.Lines[result.Selection.StartLine, 1];
    var newLine = originalLine.Replace(result.Match.Value, replaceValue);
    result.Module.ReplaceLine(result.Selection.StartLine, newLine);
}
```

an additional comment why you only process the first item in the `List<>` would help to understand this too. This comment can now be more focused on the line `RegexSearchResult result = results[0];`.

---

**`Find()`**

I don't want to write too much about this method. This method is just too big and each `case` should be extracted to a separate method.

I understand your idea about initializing the `results` at the top but would have gone a different way. By extracting the cases to methods which return a `List<>` the only time you would need the initialized `results` would be if the `switch(scope)` would go in the missing `default` case. So by returning out of the `cases` and adding the `default` case you wouldn't need to overwrite the `results` and the `switch` would get more readable. Basically you wouldn't need that variable at all.

Comment: Yeah. The library was really written for VBA devs, so the first line is one instead of zero. You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to make a recommendation for the `Find` method, following on from Heslacher's answer.

I like to use method overloading to associate related methods together.  Basically the `Find` method branches out to different implementations based on the `scope` flag.  So I recommend creating the following methods:

```
private Find(string searchPattern, Selection s);
private Find(string searchPattern, CodeModule module);
private Find(string searchPattern, IEnumerable<CodeModule> modules);
private Find(string searchPattern, VBProject project);
private Find(string searchPattern, IEnumerable<VBProject> projects);
```

These methods should be able to chain together so that `Find(string searchPattern, IEnumerable<VBProject> projects)` calls `Find(string searchPattern, VBProject project)` repeatedly for each project in its collection and aggregates the results.

You should be able to move the body of `GetResultsFromModule` into `Find(string searchPattern, CodeModule module)`.

Then you can do this:

```
public List<RegexSearchResult> Find(string searchPattern, RegexSearchReplaceScope scope)
{
    switch (scope)
    {
        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.Selection:
            Selection currentSelection;  // TODO assign this.
            return Find(searchPattern, currentSelection);

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentBlock:
            // for you to do. :D

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentFile:
            return Find(searchPattern, _model.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule);

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.AllOpenedFiles:
            IEnumerable<CodeModule> activeCodePanes; // TODO assign this.
            return Find(searchPattern, activeCodePanes);

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.CurrentProject:
            VBProject activeProject;  // TODO assign this.
            return Find(searchPattern, activeProject);

        case RegexSearchReplaceScope.AllOpenProjects:
            IEnumerable<VBProject> openProjects;  // TODO assign this.
            return Find(searchPattern, openProjects);

        default:
            throw new Exception("Arrrgggghhhh!!!!");
    }
}
```

I had to use my Notepad IDE to do this, so please excuse (and fix) any errors in my code.